# Avoid Synchronous ajax request and show loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I avoid script to process further until the response is received from the server and show some loading text or gif instead?

```
var employee = $.parseJSON(
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'get/employee/' + employee_id,
        dataType: "json", 
        async: false
    }).responseText
);
// Populate modal inputs with recieved data
$.each( employee, function( key, value ) {
    $( 'form[name="form-edit-employee"]' ).find('input[name="' + key + '"]').val( value ); 
});
$('#modal-edit-employee').modal('show');
```

Full code is available on [this link](https://github.com/surajjdhv/phonedirectory/blob/master/resources/views/pages/partials/scripts/index.blade.php).

I want to show the modal after the data is filled in inputs with an asynchronous request as synchronous requests are already depreciated on the main thread and freezes the browser window.

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: It's a little bit unclear for me. As far as I understand,  you need to run some commands only after the data fetched? You can use callbacks for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @YevheniiHerasymchuk, I really thought call back functions are not the ideal way of achieving this. My bad!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use synchronous requests. Use the asynchronous pattern properly by using callbacks, something like this:

```
var $loadingIcon = $('#yourLoadingImage').show();
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url:  'get/employee/' + employee_id,
  dataType: "json", 
  success: function(employee) {
    $.each(employee, function(key, value) {
      $('form[name="form-edit-employee"]').find('input[name="' + key + '"]').val(value); 
    });
    $('#modal-edit-employee').modal('show');
    $loadingIcon.hide();
  }
})
```

Comment: Is that $ sign before the variable name is just to distinguish between constants and variables?

Comment: It typically denotes a variable that does/should contain a jQuery object as it's value.

Comment: Got it... Thanks @Taplar